# How to control normals of spiral curve so objects in array point towards the outside

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, normals

I have a torus where I wrapped a spiral curve around using the shrinkwrap modifier. After that, I created an array and curve modifier on the "eyes" object as I want it to follow the spiral curve. The array has a constant offset on X and the curve modifier is set to the spiral curve.
Now the problem is that the normals are pointing in the wrong directions.

As you can see here, the normals are pointing to all kinds of directions
[image: As you can see here, the normals are pointing to all kinds of directions]

As you can see in the picture only the circled row is pointing right
[image: As you can see in the picture only the circled row is pointing right]

How could I control the normals of the spiral curve or how can I make sure the eyes object is facing outside like the circled row?

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris Not sure why you want the file, but I added it.

Comment: It's so we can find a solution to your specific problem without having to recreate your scene ourselves. Sharing your file is the most effective way to get people to help you with specific problems.

Comment: Allright thanks for pointing that out, will try to add a file when possible next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the curve and in the *Object Data > Shape > Twist Method*, choose *Z-Up*:

[image]

Comment: So easy! Damn I feel stupid, been looking at this problem since yesterday evening until I gave up. Thanks a lot!